# Using VB.NET to call COM interface

Tags: vb.net, com

I need to call a function that takes an array of drive letters as one of its arguments. The sample I received from the dev team that created the object uses VBScript and looks like this:

```
Array("C:","D:")
```

This doesn't work in VB.NET so I tried the following code. Note: The drives are passed to me in a comma separated string:

```
Dim drives As String = "C,D"
Dim volumeList As String() = drives.Split(","c)
For i As Integer = 0 To volumeList.Length - 1
    volumeList(i) &= ":"
Next
```

Then I try to pass volumeList to the function in question and I get an invalid argument exception. Is there some other way I could try to create/pass this array so that it acts like the VBScript example? I told the developer what I'm doing and he said "hhmm... should work." So I'd like to figure it out without having to force this guy to help me.

EDIT: The com server expects an array of type variant (VB6). That is the problem. Sadly EVERYTHING I try in VB.NET fails.

Comment: Right-click your call to the method in question and click Go To Definition. Add the method declaration to your question for more context. Also, if it's possible, see if you can get the IDL declaration from your native developer and post that on the question as well.

Comment: @BrentM.Spell - I can't go to the method definition because there is no reference in my project. I am simply going by the examples that were sent to me from their dev team.

Comment: You might try constructing a 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper
 instance from your array and then passing that down to the COM method.

Comment: @BrentM.Spell - Thanks but still no good. I get "unspecified error" when I pass a wrapped string array, and "the parameter is invalid" when I pass a wrapped object array. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB6 variant datatype is equivalent to object in VB.Net.

```
Dim drives As String = "C,D"
Dim volumeList As String() = drives.Split(","c)
' Create an object array the same length as volumeList
Dim objectArray(volumeList.Length - 1) As Object
' Add the strings to the object array
For i As Integer = 0 To volumeList.Length - 1
    objectArray(i) = volumeList(i) & ":"
Next

' Now pass the object array to your function
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get "The parameter is incorrect." And as a side note I think when you create the objectArray the length should be `volumeList.Length` (not `volumeList.Length - 1`) since you want the arrays to be the same size. But this didn't work either.